# Converting a list of strings into a single line with sed/awk on linux

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file say test.txt, which contains data as a list of values/strings and also has some empty lines in between as shown below

```
Val1  
Val2  
Val3

Val4  
Val5         
         
     
    
Val6
```

**Required output:**

```
Val1, Val2, Val3  
Val4, Val5  
Val6
```

I am using the below command, but it's returning all the available values in a single line. But I want only consecutive values to be concatenated together(comma separated) and a new line should start whenever it hits an empty line (there can be more than one consecutive empty line).

`cat test.txt | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g' | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/.*/&/;$!s/$/, /' | tr -d '\n'`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do, using any awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' -v OFS=', ' '{$1=$1} 1' test.txt
Val1, Val2, Val3
Val4, Val5
Val6
```

Comment: An accepted answer should come with the relevant explanation or a bit of hints. The man page is huge and one can get lost (if the fundamentals was so obvious for the OP, this one shouldn't have post such a question) Did you mind if I edit your answer @EdMorton ?

Comment: @gilldux I disagree with you and I'd prefer if you don't. Anyone who knows awk fundamentals doesn't need an explanation for this code and anyone who doesn't should read a little awk documentation to learn about a lot more than just what this answer is doing.

Comment: It would be good to add explanations of what the options, matching and actions are.

Comment: @PaulFloyd it's not reasonable to expect an explanation of awk fundamentals in every awk answer.

Answer (score 4):

***1st solution:*** With your shown samples only, please try following GNU `awk` code.

```bash
awk -v RS=  'RT{gsub(/\n/,", ");print}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With GNU `awk` and with your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk -v RS='([^\n]*\n)+' '
RT && num=split(RT,arr,"\n\n"){
  val=""
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
     sub(/,$/,"",arr[i])
     gsub(/\n+/,", ",arr[i])
     print arr[i]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

With `gnu-sed` you can read the whole file with `-z`

Capture 2 non newlines in 2 capture groups surrounding a single newline, and in the replacement use 2 backreferences with `,`  in between

Then replace 2 or more newlines with a single newline.

```
sed -Ez 's/([^\n])\n([^\n])/\1, \2/g;s/\n{2,}/\n/g' file
```

Output

```
Val1, Val2, Val3
Val4, Val5
Val6
```

Using only sed `-E` you can accomplish the same using a label reading all lines:

```
sed -E ':a;$!{N;ba};s/([^\n])\n([^\n])/\1, \2/g;s/\n{2,}/\n/g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one:

```
awk '{if(NF){if(line!="")line=line", "$0;else line=$0;}else{if(line!=""){print line;line=""} } } END{if(line) print line}' test.txt
```

Output:

Val1, Val2, Val3
Val4, Val5
Val6

Comment: `if(!line)` would fail if the first line contained the number `0`, you need `if (line != "")` instead. Also, `{if(NF){` = `NF{`.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for the suggestion. The answer is updated, however I was unable to make the `{if(NF){` = `NF{` simplification.

Comment: What stopped you from being able to make that change? Did you maybe not remove the matching `}` at the end of the statement when you removed it from the beginning?

Comment: @EdMorton the problem is that i do not know how to implement the `else` statement in the command when using `NF{` instead of  `{if(NF){`. I guess i could write the command also as  `awk 'NF{if(line!="")line=line", "$0;else line=$0;}{if(NF==0){if(line!=""){print line;line=""} }  } END{if(line) print line}' test.txt` but that does not seem to make the command simpler.

Comment: Ah, I see, I didn't notice that `else` was associated with the `NF` test - it's very hard to read code that's all crammed together on one line with no white space and I wasn't expecting there to be an `else` to that.

Answer (score 2):

If GNU/BSD `ed` is available/acceptable.

```
ed -s file.txt <<-'EOF'
  ,$-1g/.\{1,\}/;/^$/-1s/$/, /
  ,$-1g/.\{1,\}/;/^$/j
  g/^$/d
  %s/, *$//
  %p
  Q
EOF
```

---

In one line, something like:

```
printf '%b\n' ',$-1g/.\{1,\}/;/^$/-1s/$/, /' ',$-1g/.\{1,\}/;/^$/j' 'g/^$/d' '%s/, *$//' %p Q | ed -s file.txt
```

Comment: What implementation of `ed` are you using? I was sure this won't work on any POSIX compliant implementation and that's what happen when I give a try in an interactive session: the first line yield `?` and when I ask `h` it replies `invalid adress` as I guess. After loading the file, the last line should be reached, hence `,$-1` means `$,$-1` which is an illegal range as it must be in ascending order...

Comment: @gldux, GNU ed(1), `,$-1` is a shorthand for `1,$-1` at least in on this side.

Comment: @gildux, tested also on ed from FreeBSD121

Comment: @gildux, https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ed.html, look for the `Addresses in ed`, or you could try `PAGER='less +/\ Addresses\ in\ ed' man 1p ed`

Comment: You're right, the error was somewhere else… `,$-1g/.\{1,\}/;/^$/ n` is fine but `,$-1g/.\{1,\}/;/^$/- n` is on error here (not GNU but one of the BSD implementation shiped with Mac OS X)

Comment: @gildux, yeah `-s` is a shorthand for `-1s` at least on this side as well, updated to use `1`.

Comment: @gildux, `A <plus-sign> ( '+' ) or <hyphen-minus> character ( '-' ) followed by a decimal number shall address the current line plus or minus the number. A <plus-sign> or <hyphen-minus> character not followed by a decimal number shall address the current line plus or minus 1.`  From POSIX `ed` , maybe you have a different version of `ed` ?

Comment: `,$-1g/.\{1,\}/;/^$/ n` gives lines: 1 2 3 4 2 3 4 3 4 ? I had no error in first try because I forgot `n` or `p` (I think it's a bug I should report) `,$-1g/.\{1,\}/;/^$/- n` gives lines: 1 2 3 2 3 3 ? Something is wrong in the adresses consumed by `g` here, at least within my implementation that conform all POSIX tests I've tried.

Comment: OK, got it: when I add a last blank line to the `file.txt` there's no more error. `$-1g/.\{1,\}/;/^$/ n` gives lines: 10 11 only; and `,$-1g/.\{1,\}/;/^$/- n` outputs lines: 1 2 3 2 3 3 5 6 7 8 9 10 6 7 8 9 10 7 8 9 10 8 9 10 9 10 10 now. You had a last empty line I didn't have, hence the failure when I tried your solution. However, there's still one issue: the result on my side is `Val1  , Val2  , Val3` and `Val4  , Val5         ,          ,      ,     , Val6`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/\n$//;t;s/\n/, /;ta' file
```

Append the following line and if that line is empty, remove and print the result.

Otherwise, replace the newline by `,`  and repeat.